# Foundation, Close all open off-canvas menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6 and have introduced some off canvas menus.  They work great, I click "Tray One", it opens and at the same time toggles the slide show so it is hidden at the same time.

But I want to extend this further so that when I click on say "Tray Two", it opens the corresponding off canvas menu, but closes any other open menus.

How do I go about doing this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-essential/6.2.2/css/app.css">
</head>
<body zf-close-all>

    <nav data-mainbar role="navigation">
     <ul class="dropdown menu bg" data-dropdown-menu>
      <!-- These data-toggles need to close any other open menus on click? -->
      <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" data-toggle="one_tray slideshow">Tray One</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" data-toggle="two_tray slideshow">Tray Two</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#" data-toggle="three_tray slideshow">Tray Three</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="off-canvas-content tray" data-off-canvas-content="">
     <div id="one_tray" class="toggle tray_item hide" data-toggler=".hide" data-transition="push" aria-expanded="true">
      <p>Tray One</p>
     </div>
     <div id="two_tray" class="toggle tray_item hide" data-toggler=".hide" data-transition="push" aria-expanded="true">
      <p>Tray Two</p>
     </div>
     <div id="three_tray" class="toggle tray_item hide" data-toggler=".hide" data-transition="push" aria-expanded="true">
      <p>Tray Three</p>
     </div>
    </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-essential/6.2.2/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a working code.. so i can check

Comment: I have amended to include full working cdn example.

Comment: I think you have to use custom jquery here

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/andycochran/pen/yedGeL

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns large-5">
    <button class="button popup-button" data-popup="popup-1">Callout 1</button>
    <button class="button popup-button" data-popup="popup-2">Callout 2</button>
    <button class="button popup-button" data-popup="popup-3">Callout 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="columns large-7">
    <div class="callout popup hide" id="popup-1">
      <h2>Callout One</h2>
      <button class="close-button popup-close-button" type="button">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="callout popup hide" id="popup-2">
      <h2>Callout Two</h2>
      <button class="close-button popup-close-button" type="button">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="callout popup hide" id="popup-3">
      <h2>Callout Three</h2>
      <button class="close-button popup-close-button" type="button">&times;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$( '.popup-button' ).click(function() {
    $( '.popup' ).addClass( 'hide' );
    var thePopup = jQuery( this ).data( 'popup' );
    $( '#'+thePopup ).removeClass( 'hide' );
});

$( '.popup-close-button' ).click(function() {
    $( '.popup' ).addClass( 'hide' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is better, BUT it doesn't close when the same popup-button link is clicked again.